# How to remove ^C from the path directory terminal [Linux]

Tags: linux

In Linux when I type "CTRL+C" to cancel the current line and move to the next, I get the following symbol "^C" below showing that I have cancelled the previous command as shown below:

```
sqldba@SQL-linux-001:/etc# ^C    
sqldba@SQL-linux-001:/etc#
```

I would like to remove the "^C" symbol from showing when I cancel from my previous command and show it as below without the "^C" symbol. Basically the same as when you press enter on an empty line, it will show the below. I would like the same as when "CTRL+C" is used

```
sqldba@SQL-linux-001:/etc#     
sqldba@SQL-linux-001:/etc#
```

I am unsure of the file to edit to make this change, whether it can be done in the .bashrc profile or the .bash_profile

Thanks.

Comment: ^C is the cancel. It happens when you 'Control-C' a command. Is that part of the directory name or were you trying to cancel a command when that happened??

Comment: Yes when I press 'Control-C' it shows that, but I do not want it to show that

Answer (score 1):

pipe it through a stream editor. Try this:

```
echo $PATH | sed 's/^C//g'
```

Not entirely sure this is what you want, so please clarify. What this will do is remove all instances of ^C from your PATH system variable.

If this is not what you want, take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path as well as `man sed`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work